# Is it normal for my PSU to not have a 4-pin connector?

Tags: power-supply

I have connected all the power (fan, motherboard, optical drive, SATA HDD). But I have not powered the processor because I cannot find a 4 pin connector from my PSU! How do I work around this? There are no 4+4 or 4+2 connectors either it is a generic and old PSU

Comment: If it's really old then it may not have one. But then it's so old you shouldn't be using it if you don't want to risk frying other components. And even if it's preserved well, it probably has incorrect 5V/12V balance and may not provide enough power for your PC even if wattage looks sufficient.

Comment: Right it has a matching motherboard that came with it that is also from my old computer but was just lazy to remove everything. I guess I have no choice to replace the board as well. Frying the other components would not be a big problem as they are all about 7-8 years old

Comment: a 7 to 8 year old PSU, or even a 10-15 year old one should have CPU power. Is it a modular unit?

Comment: Pictures would help.